# why does my horizontal scrolling site lose the navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

here is the site: http://100.365fragments.com/

here is the html for the navigation portion:

```
           <div class="content_nav">stranger &#35; 
            <a href="#stranger1" class="panel">1</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger2" class="panel">2</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger3" class="panel">3</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger4" class="panel">4</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger5" class="panel">5</a> |
            <a href="#stranger6" class="panel">6</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger7" class="panel">7</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger8" class="panel">8</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger9" class="panel">9</a> |
            <a href="#stranger10" class="panel">10</a> |
            <a href="#stranger11" class="panel">11</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger12" class="panel">12</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger13" class="panel">13</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger14" class="panel">14</a> |
            <a href="#stranger15" class="panel">15</a> |
            <a href="#stranger16" class="panel">16</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger17" class="panel">17</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger18" class="panel">18</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger19" class="panel">19</a> |
            <a href="#stranger20" class="panel">20</a> |
            <a href="#stranger21" class="panel">21</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger22" class="panel">22</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger23" class="panel">23</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger24" class="panel">24</a> |
            <a href="#stranger25" class="panel">25</a> |
            <a href="#stranger26" class="panel">26</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger27" class="panel">27</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger28" class="panel">28</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger29" class="panel">29</a> |
            <a href="#stranger30" class="panel">30</a> |
            <a href="#stranger31" class="panel">31</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger32" class="panel">32</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger33" class="panel">33</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger34" class="panel">34</a> |
            <a href="#stranger35" class="panel">35</a> |
            <a href="#stranger36" class="panel">36</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger37" class="panel">37</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger38" class="panel">38</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger39" class="panel">39</a> |
            <a href="#stranger40" class="panel">40</a> |
            <a href="#stranger41" class="panel">41</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger42" class="panel">42</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger43" class="panel">43</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger44" class="panel">44</a> |
            <a href="#stranger45" class="panel">45</a> |
            <a href="#stranger46" class="panel">46</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger47" class="panel">47</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger48" class="panel">48</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger49" class="panel">49</a> |
            <a href="#stranger50" class="panel">50</a> |
            <a href="#stranger51" class="panel">51</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger52" class="panel">52</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger53" class="panel">53</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger54" class="panel">54</a> |
            <a href="#stranger55" class="panel">55</a> |
            <a href="#stranger56" class="panel">56</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger57" class="panel">57</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger58" class="panel">58</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger59" class="panel">59</a> |
            <a href="#stranger60" class="panel">60</a> |
            <a href="#stranger61" class="panel">61</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger62" class="panel">62</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger63" class="panel">63</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger64" class="panel">64</a> |
            <a href="#stranger65" class="panel">65</a> |
            <a href="#stranger66" class="panel">66</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger67" class="panel">67</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger68" class="panel">68</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger69" class="panel">69</a> |
            <a href="#stranger70" class="panel">70</a> |
            <a href="#stranger71" class="panel">71</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger72" class="panel">72</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger73" class="panel">73</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger74" class="panel">74</a> |
            <a href="#stranger75" class="panel">75</a> |
            <a href="#stranger76" class="panel">76</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger77" class="panel">77</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger78" class="panel">78</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger79" class="panel">79</a> |
            <a href="#stranger80" class="panel">80</a> |
            <a href="#stranger81" class="panel">81</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger82" class="panel">82</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger83" class="panel">83</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger84" class="panel">84</a> |
            <a href="#stranger85" class="panel">85</a> |
            <a href="#stranger86" class="panel">86</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger87" class="panel">87</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger88" class="panel">88</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger89" class="panel">89</a> |                
            <a href="#stranger90" class="panel">90</a> |
            <a href="#stranger91" class="panel">91</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger92" class="panel">92</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger93" class="panel">93</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger94" class="panel">94</a> |
            <a href="#stranger95" class="panel">95</a> |
            <a href="#stranger96" class="panel">96</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger97" class="panel">97</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger98" class="panel">98</a> | 
            <a href="#stranger99" class="panel">99</a> |
            <a href="#stranger100" class="panel">100</a> 


        </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
      body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;left:0;
background-color:#ccc;
overflow:hidden;
    }

#mask {
    width:10000%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.stranger {
    width:1%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ddd;
}


.content {
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    top:20%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#aaa;
    position:relative;
}



.content {
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    top:8%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#aaa;
    position:relative;
}

    #nav_content {
           width: 800px;
           height: 100px;
           top:60%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right:auto;
           display:block;
           text-align:center;
    background-color:#aaa;

    }

    content_nav {
          width: 800px;
          height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
           margin-right:auto;
           display:block;
           text-align:center;
    background-color:#aaa;
    }

.selected {
    background:#fff;
    font-weight:700;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}


.selected {
    background:#fff;
    font-weight:700;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

    </style>
```

When you view the second link, it scrolls to the right box, however, the navigation goes off the screen. I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong. Would welcome advice on this.

Thanks

Comment: ...but where's the javascript?

Comment: Jeez. OK, every section has the same menu entered in every time. There should be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `.content_nav { position:fixed; }` what you're looking for? With that set (and tweaked to your requirements) you'll only need one menu which will be visible the whole time.

Also, your CSS is missing a period before `content_nav` so add one in (since it's a class) and those styles should work.

Comment: thank you that works - an obvious mistake, but one that completely slipped me. just one thing though, the first link is fine, the second link still scrolls diagonally downwards, with the rest working fine, and scrolling back it's fine too. Any idea why the second link does this? sorry about editing your post btw I mistakenly edited the wrong one